# Understanding how DropDownListFor is working in MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, drop-down-menu, html.dropdownlistfor

I'm new to MVC3 and have been working on a small site using EF and 'Code First'. I'm trying to do a few things in a view dealing with a drop down list and am wondering what the best way to go about them is.  I want a user to be able to select a rule from the dropdownlist, and depending upon which rule was selected, I would like a label on the page to show the rule name (without posting).  I also need to be able to send the selected rule onto the next page.  I haven't added all of the necessary fields to the view yet because I'm really at a loss on how it should work.  How should I go about trying to do this?

I've got my model:

```
public class D1K2N3CARule
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public int Name { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Rule { get; set; }

    public D1K2N3CARule(int name, string rule)
    {
        Name = name;
        Rule = rule;
    }
    public D1K2N3CARule()
    {
        Name = 0;
        Rule = "";
    }
}
```

My ViewModel:

```
public class D1K2N3CARuleViewModel
{
    public string SelectedD1K2N3CARuleId { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<D1K2N3CARule> D1K2N3CARules { get; set; }
}
```

My Controller:

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var model = new D1K2N3CARuleViewModel
        {
            D1K2N3CARules = db.D1K2N3DARules
        };

        return View(model);
    }
```

and my View:

```
'@model CellularAutomata.Models.D1K2N3CARuleViewModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}
<asp:Content id="head" contentplaceholderid="head" runat="server">
<script type="text/javascript">
</script>
</asp:Content>
<h2>Index</h2>

<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DropDownListFor(
                x => x.D1K2N3CARules,
                new SelectList(Model.D1K2N3CARules, "ID","Rule")
            )
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I want a user to be able to select a rule from the dropdownlist, and depending upon which rule was selected, I would like a label on the page to show the rule name (without posting)

You will need javascript here. jQuery would be perfect for the job. I would start by providing a deterministic id for the dropdown because if you run this view inside a template there could be prefixes added to the id which would ruin our javascript id selectors (see below):

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(
    x => x.D1K2N3CARules,
    new SelectList(Model.D1K2N3CARules, "ID", "Rule"),
    new { id = "ruleDdl" }
)
```

then provide some container which will receive the selected value:

```
<div id="ruleValue" />
```

and finally in a separate javascript file subscribe for the change event of the dropdown list and update the container with the selected value/text:

```
$(function() {
    // subscribe for the change event of the dropdown
    $('#ruleDdl').change(function() {
        // get the selected text from the dropdown
        var selectedText = $(this).find('option:selected').text();

        // if you wanted the selected value you could:
        // var selectedValue = $(this).val();

        // show the value inside the container
        $('#ruleValue').html(selectedText);
    });
});
```

> I also need to be able to send the selected rule onto the next page.

You could put your dropdown inside a form

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("NextPage", "Foo"))
{
    @Html.DropDownListFor(
        x => x.D1K2N3CARules,
        new SelectList(Model.D1K2N3CARules, "ID","Rule")
    )    
    <input type="submit" value="Go to the next page" />
}
```

and the NextPage controller action will receive the selected value.

Comment: What parameter gets passed back to the next page controller?  Everything I try ends up coming through null.  I've looked around for the last few hours for an answer and just keep coming up empty. Do you have any suggestions for a good resource on MVC3?  I've obviously been spinning my wheels a bit and I think I need to do some reading.

Comment: @Doug S., only what you include in the form will get passed to the next controller. In this example we only have a dropdownlist so, only the selected value will be sent.

Comment: I understand that, but what parameter do I specify in my nextpage controller? 

public ActionResult RunCA(string id)
or
public ActionResult RunCA(selectlistitem item)
or
public ActionResult RunCA(int id)

Everything I've tried has comeback null.

Comment: @Doug S.: `public ActionResult RunCA(string selectedD1K2N3CARuleId)`. And by the way your `DropDownListFor` helper usage is wrong as you are using the same property (`D1K2N3CARules`) for both the selected value and the items. It should be: `@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.SelectedD1K2N3CARuleId, new SelectList(Model.D1K2N3CARules, "ID","Rule"))`. This will allow you to fetch the selected value (`SelectedD1K2N3CARuleId`) on the next page.