# How to create a DropDownList from a LINQ query in MVC3?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, linq, selectlist, html.dropdownlistfor

I need to know how I could create a drop down list to represent all the categories in my "Categories" table.

I have already extracted the names and the values of each category I need, using this LINQ query :

```
var dbcontext = new LNQ2SQLDataContext();
        var Q = from P in dbcontext.Categories
                where P.SUB_CAT == null
                select P;
```

I can pass this "Q" to my view like this :
In Controller :

```
return View(Q);
```

And in the View :

```
@model IEnumerable<MyAppName.Models.Category>
```

But I have no idea how to use `@html.DropDownListFor()` to make a darn good drop down list out of the model. :|

**PLUS:**

I could make a `SelectList` from the query "Q" like this :

```
var category_list = new SelectList(Q, "CAT_ID", "CAT_Name");
```

**BUT** I don't know how to create a drop down list (without using `ViewBag` to pass the `category_list` to the view) from a simple `SelectList`, either :|

I searched through as many blogs and websites as I could. But they didn't have the solution for my problem. I only got more and more confused!

So can anybody help please ? :/

Comment: [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5070762/mvc3-razor-html-dropdownlistfor) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3057873/how-to-write-a-simple-html-dropdownlistfor) may be helpful...

Comment: and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5098848/help-me-understand-understand-how-to-work-with-dropdownlistfor-in-mvc3?rq=1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use DropDownListFor you'll either have to have a model that has a SelectList or data to make a selectlist out of and a property to store the selected value of the dropdown OR use the ViewBag to pass the category_list. So you can go with...

```
Public Class MyViewModel
{
    Public Integer SelectedCategory { get; set; }
    Public SelectList Categories { get; set; }
}

Public Class ItemsController : Controller
{
    Public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var dbcontext = new LNQ2SQLDataContext();
        var Q = from P in dbcontext.Categories
                where P.SUB_CAT == null
                select P;
        var vm = new MyViewModel();
        vm.Categories = new SelectList(Q, "CategoryID", "Name");
        return View(vm);
    }

    [HttpPost()]
    Public ActionResult Index(MyViewModel vm)
    {
        var theSelectedCategory = vm.SelectedCategory;
    }
}
```

The view would be...

```
@model MyViewModel
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SelectedCategory, Model.Categories, "Select Category")
```

Note: I don't typically code in C# so I can't guarantee the syntax is exactly right.

Comment: It returns error in the [httppost] actionresult, though...
Says the Model is null !!

Comment: Are you using `@Using Html.BeginForm` around the `@Html.DropDownListFor` and submit button?

Comment: Yes I'm using @Using.BeginForm around that !

Comment: This was OP's first post. I suspect he would have voted up the answer if he could have.