# How to create a DropDownList from a LINQ query

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, html-helper, html.dropdownlistfor

I'm trying to use the results of a LINQ query to create a dropdownlist in an MVC app. I'm using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11758747/how-to-create-a-dropdownlist-from-a-linq-query-in-mvc3) as a reference. However, when I try to implement for my case I get the error: `'System.String' does not contain a property with the name 'SAMPLING_EVENT'`

My code is as follows:

Controller

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    //
    // GET: /Home/

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        ViewBag.Title = "Sample Tracker Tool";
        DateTime nineMonthsAgo = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-270);

        var context = new EDMS_Entities();
        var resultSet = (from samplingEvents in context.EDMS_SAMPLES
                        where samplingEvents.RECORD_CREATED_DATE >= nineMonthsAgo
                        orderby samplingEvents.SAMPLING_EVENT
                        select samplingEvents.SAMPLE_ID)
                        .Distinct();

        var viewModel = new SamplingEventsVM();
        viewModel.SamplingEvents = new SelectList(resultSet, "SAMPLING_EVENT", "SAMPLING_EVENT");

        return View(viewModel);
    }
}
```

ViewModel class

```
public class SamplingEventsVM
{
    public int SelectedSamplingEvent { get; set; }
    public SelectList SamplingEvents { get; set; }
}
```

View

```
@model SamplingEventsVM

<h2>@ViewBag.Title</h2>

<span>
    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SelectedSamplingEvent, Model.SamplingEvents, "Sampling Event")
</span>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are selecting this `select samplingEvents.SAMPLE_ID`

So you get a List of `int` *maybe, depends on your ID type*

Then you try to make a select list with the property value `"SAMPLING_EVENT"`

Which doesn't exist on the `int` object you filled resultSet with.

Instead do this:

```
    var resultSet = (from samplingEvents in context.EDMS_SAMPLES
                    where samplingEvents.RECORD_CREATED_DATE >= nineMonthsAgo
                    orderby samplingEvents.SAMPLING_EVENT
                    select samplingEvents)
                    .Distinct();
```

Comment: I just figured this out shortly before your response - thanks for the answer! :)

Comment: No problem. I actually Hadn't seen SelectList and always using LINQ to return a list of select items. Great Class to learn about... a year late... @ChrisV.

Comment: Glad you got something out of it too, then! ;]